# Sharepoint WebApplication Localhost works but not ip

Tags: sharepoint, iis, ip, localhost

i have the following Environment:

- SharePoint server 2010
- Windows server 2008 R2
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- Im not in a domain its pure standalone server.

i have a website configured to use port 88 and a site collection.

problem is i could browse the site using the following URL :

```
http://localhost:88
```

but not :

```
http://192.168.1.8:88
```

it generate this error :

```
[FileNotFoundException: The Web application at http://192.168.1.8:88/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, SPUserToken userToken) +27650365
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl) +110
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.IdentityModelSignInPageBase.SetThreadCultureFromRequestedWeb() +64
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +143
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1477
```

I`m sure of the IP and the port..

plus share point central Administration works with both

```
http://192.168.1.8:15769
and 
http://localhost:15769
```

any idea what the problem could be ?

Comment: Have you tried added a alternate access mapping for that site collection in central admin?

Comment: i forgot to provide the the error sorry plz check my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you configure your alternate access mappings correctly. Here is more information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814(office.12).aspx (it's for SharePoint 2007, but the principles are the same in 2010)

Comment: "there are common Internet deployment scenarios in which the URL of a Web request received by Internet Information Services (IIS) is not the same as the URL that was typed by an end user"
i dont think this is the  case here as both url reflect the same destination other wise how come sharepoint central Administration works ?